# Do I need actually to upgrade laravel from 5.1 to 5.2?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Is there any serious reason for which I will must upgrade the laravel from 5.1 to 5.2 Or in the future to 5.3 and so on ?

Comment: Serious do you mean feature wise or security wise?

Comment: you need to upgrade at least once in 3 years for the security fixes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L5.1 provide LTS (Long Term Support) and as of now, L5.2 doesn't. So it's not a mandatory that you should upgrade to L5.2 rightway. If your application is working fine on L5.1 and is on production, then keep it as it is.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/releases#laravel-5.1